# Drupal - (Profile2) Profile types does not show form on multistep wizard

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created multistep registration form with multistep registration module and profile2 module.

Steps:

1. User enters info on step 1 which is username and password then click on continue button
2. User enters profile info on step 2 and hit continue
3. User enter organization info on step 3 and finish.

I would like the user to enter contact info on step 2, and pre-populate it on step 3.

I made custom module and used:

```
function fs_prepopulate_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
}
```

I am trying to use `var_dump($form);` on step 2 and step 3 but it does not show any form fields.

Answer (score 0):

After working few days on this issue, I finally got the solution. I used
hook_form_profile2_form_alter instead of using hook_form_alter to get the profile2 form fields.Here is the  link for profile2 reference help http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/profile2/profile2.module. I hope this information would save someone's time.